# Nightwatch vs. self signed certificates

Tags: ssl, nightwatch.js

My [nightwatch.js](http://nightwatchjs.org) setup for Geckodriver is as follows:

```
    "firefox": {
        "launch_url": "...",
        "selenium_port": 4444,
        "selenium_host": "localhost",
        "silent": true,
        ...
        "desiredCapabilities": {
            "browserName": "gecko",
            "marionette": true,
            "acceptSslCerts": true
        }
    }
```

When running, all tests fail because my certificate is insecure testing on a local installation and enforced ssl. Chromedriver (with basically identical setup) seems to accept the "acceptSslCerts" property and ignores the wrong cert. Geckodriver does not. Is the config wrong or does Nightwatch or Selenium have a problem with "acceptSslCerts"?

I am using the latest version of Geckodriver and Selenium 3.8.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the correct capability for the firefox driver is `acceptInsecureCerts`.

You can see it listed [here](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html#dfn-insecure-tls-certificates).